# sculpting is pretty much smooth

Tags: mesh, sculpting, brushes

hey all I Don t Know what this exactly called, since I m New at scultping watched some tutorial but i really could n't find a solution as far as I know , so I M doing a face sculpting and I am trying to sculpt a mouth but every time I try crease pen , the crease is pretty smooth as you can see in the picture , I dont want it to be smooth I want it to be like normal so I can Smooth it with smooth pen (shift)
note : that I quit blender to take a rest and before that crease pen was not a smooth as when I came back to it
I hope you understand what I Meant, and thank you for your support [image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVf-UvySGqI&t=1071s&ab_channel=PIXXO3D
I have this tutorial at 19:55 His brush is like that i want to make it same as This brush
[image]

Comment: Have you tried incrreasing the strenght of the brush? It's like something about 0.5 right now

Comment: you can check my edit commented there , thanks

Comment: hello maybe share your file so that we try

Answer (score 2):

You just have to decrease your radius value. Because your radius is relatively large, the effect of the crease brush was spread over a large area as well.

[image]